# How to recognize a gYear value?

Tags: xml, types, semantic-web

As we know, each xml datatype has a specific format.
For example:

> xs:gYearMonth  => 2001-10 or 2001-10+02:00 or 2001-10Z ... xs:dateTime
>   => 2001-10-26T21:32:52 or 2001-10-26T21:32:52+02:00 or 2001-10-26T19:32:52Z ...

In the case of xs:gYear => these are all the possibilities:

> 2001, 2001+02:00, 2001Z, 2001+00:00,
>   -2001,
>   -20000

and the datatype xs:Decimal :

> 123,
>   123.456,
>   +1234.456,
>   -1234.456,
>   -.456,
>   -456

So there is small intersection (values 2001, 123), how can i know if the value is a gYear or Decimal datatype?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.

Or at least, you can't always tell from the lexical representation alone.

As such you can't know from that alone whether `2016` means the current year or the number of 5-cubes in a 9-cube.

You need to infer from context or other information (schema annotations).